# What is the difference between depth and arrayLength in MTLTexture of iOS Metal

Tags: ios, metal

The document says: "For 1D, 2D, and cube textures, the depth value is 1". But in an MTLTexture of type 2DArray, isn't the depth also 1?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. For purposes of that documentation, a 2DArray texture falls under 2D textures. (It's conceptually an array of 2D textures, all of whose `depth` is 1.) It's a roundabout way of saying "For non-3D textures, the depth value is 1".